# Rendering templates with data from iron-router server route

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm new in Meteor.js and have a basic question. I want to render a template with data from server side route with iron-router module. I used **where: 'server'** in my route obtion (from [this link](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing)) but render function ( this.render() ) not fired.

I successfully done this by using NodeJS Request and Response object (as above example) but I want to pass data to template and render the template from server.

This is my route code:

```
Router.route('/movie/title', function () {

    var request = Meteor.npmRequire('request');
    var future = new (Npm.require('fibers/future'))();

    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            future.return(body);
        }
        else {
            future.throw(error);
        }
    })

    var myResult = future.wait();
    console.log(myResult);
    this.render('test', {
        data: { result: myResult }
    });
}, { where: 'server' });
```

And this is my template code:

```
<head>
  <title>Search your favorite movie</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}

</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="test">
{{result}}
</template>
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here, as soon as iron-router updates its guide or moves it it will become worthless.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I've added router and template codes on question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Iron Router Cheatsheet](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-11-iron-router-cheatsheet/18), render is not available on the server:

> ```
> # When you define a server route (via where: 'server'), you need to define the action function, and use in a fairly simplistic way, much like express.
> # The render method is not available.
> ```

It doesn't appear to have been updated in 6 months, and I can't find anything in the [Iron Router Guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#client-only) or the [readme on GitHub](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router) about it only being available on the client, but my guess is that's the problem.

If you really need to render from the server, you might check out [meteorhacks:ssr](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/ssr) (server-side rendering); there appears to be a pretty in-depth post about it on the [meteorhacks site](https://meteorhacks.com/server-side-rendering.html) as well.

From the readme of that package, it looks like the way forward with your particular problem is to define your templates in the private/ directory, then call the compileTemplate method on the server:

```
<!--template in private/hello.html-->
<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<!--Another template in private/test.html -->
<template name="test">
  {{result}}
</template>
```

You'll want to define any helpers on the server as well, and compile the template on the server:

```
// in server/test.js
SSR.compileTemplate('test', Assets.getText('test.html')
```

You can then use the SSR package to render the template on the server with data, which will return the HTML as a string; you could implement it with a Meteor Method to get the HTML back to the client:

```
// You can call this method from the client to get the rendered template back:
Meteor.methods('renderTest', function(data) { 
  return SSR.render('test', data);
});
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26322794/server-side-rendering-with-meteor-and-meteorhacksssr-and-iron-router) for significantly more detail on using SSR and iron:router in conjunction.

Comment: This is a great answer. I'm surprised no one had up-voted it yet.